# ¿Como puedo usar fetch en el front para enviar data hacia nodeJS?(ajax)

Tags: javascript, ajax, nodejs

quisiera enviar la info desde fetch hacia nodeJS(Express Js) , poder recibirla en el backend y enviar una respuesta nuevamente hacia el frontend y recibir la respuesta, como podría conseguir esto?, intente con el siguiente code, cualquier ayuda es gratamente recibida , gracias!

Code frontend:

```javascript
formGuardar.addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const info = { test: 'Texto de prueba' };
  fetch("/guardar", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { 
        "Content-type": "application/json"
     },
    body: JSON.stringify(info),
  })
  .then(resp =>{
    console.log(resp)
  })
  .catch(error =>{
    console.log("Hubo un error inesperado " + error)
  })
});
```

Route :

```javascript
router.use("/guardar",guardarUsuario)
```

controller :

```javascript
const guardarUsuario = (req,resp) =>{
    console.log(req.body.test)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Backend**

```
app.post('/guardar', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.test);
  res.json({ mensaje: 'recibido!' });
});
```

**Frontend**

```
fetch('/guardar', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
     Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(info)
})
.then(resp => resp.json())
.then(data => {
  console.log(data.mensaje);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log('Error! ' + error);
});
```

Comment: Hola!, Gracias por comentar... Intenté lo que posteaste y me devuelve este error : Hubo un error inesperado SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON , al parecer me devuelve HTML , aunque desconozco la causa... Es posible que tenga una ruta equivocada? intente con una ruta absoluta y tampoco

Comment: En las herramientas de desarrollo checa que respuesta estas recibiendo en la pestaña de Redes / Network

Comment: Me ha devolvido un Estado : 200, Tipo : Fetch en mi archivo app.js *.*

Comment: El error 200 indica que si se hizo la solicitud HTTP y que el server regreso una respuesta, en headers agrega `Accept: "application/json"`, de igual forma ya lo edité en el código.

Comment: Muchas gracias rené ya pude solucionarlo, te agradezco la ayuda!!